# How to avoid avoid inserting duplicates many rows at a time in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to log when formtype or batch type is mismatched between tables. I am able to do this by succesfully with below code but I am unable to avoid inserting duplicates.
I tried adding not in and not exists but it is still returning results and duplicating the entries everytime.

```
   Insert into tblsalesforceAttachmentSync (AttachmentId, ErrorMessage )
    select distinct sfa.attachmentId
    --, sfas.attachmentid
    --,sfas.attachmentid, 
    ,Errormessage = Case when img.BatchType is null then 'BatchType is not valid. '
    end +
    case when img.DocType is null then ' FormType is not valid.' 
    end
     from #salesforceAttachment sfa
      left join tblSalesforceAttachmentSync sfas on sfas.AttachmentId = sfa.AttachmentId
     left outer join dbo.tblImageBarcodes img on img.BatchType = sfa.BatchType
     and 
     img.DocType = 
     sfa.Form_Type 
     where img.DocType is null 
           or img.BatchType is null 

     Below doesnt work


 and not exists (select AttachmentId from tblSalesforceAttachmentSync sa where sa.AttachmentId = sfa.AttachmentId )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Insert into tblsalesforceAttachmentSync (AttachmentId, ErrorMessage )
    select distinct sfa.attachmentId
    --, sfas.attachmentid
    --,sfas.attachmentid, 
    ,Errormessage = Case when img.BatchType is null then 'BatchType is not valid. '
    end +
    case when img.DocType is null then ' FormType is not valid.' 
    end
     from #salesforceAttachment sfa
      left join tblSalesforceAttachmentSync sfas on sfas.AttachmentId = sfa.AttachmentId
     left outer join dbo.tblImageBarcodes img on img.BatchType = sfa.BatchType
     and 
     img.DocType = 
     sfa.Form_Type 
     where (img.DocType is null 
           or img.BatchType is null)
and sfas.AttachmentId is null
```

Its a little funny because you dont need the table tblSalesforceAttachmentSync in the query

Comment: your answer worked but I am not understanding how this could be accomplished without the tblSalesforceAttachmentSync in the query